# Portable X11 for Linux(Debian Wheezy)

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

I need a portable X11 server. That is - everything to be in one directory - configs, shared libs, binaries, etc. How should I go about achieving this? The idea is to put X11 in my initrd. I am using Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Why does it have to be "portable"? The initrd is a full system with `/usr/lib` and `/etc` and you can copy any program to it – the same way most distros install things like `udev` and `cryptsetup` there.

Comment: Well, if it's portable I feel it will be more elegant.